# How to distinguish between programmatic and operational errors using promised-based node.js coding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am quite new to node.js but I totally love it. However, I am strugling to understand proper error handling.

Over web there are a lot of good resources about that but they mostly are old and refer to callback-based programing. I prefer to use promises. With promises it is even more easier to handle errors as you dont have to duplicate code for every operational error that could happen - instead you just catch it once and handle (or propagate to caller).

However in node it is important to distinguish between error type and perform gracefull crash and restart of application if programmatic error has happened. Consider this callback-based code example:|

```
function myFunc (input, cb){
    if(typeof input === 'undefined'){
        throw new Error('Invalid argument');
    }
    asinc1(input, function(e, data){
        if(err) return cb(e, null);
        asinc2(data, function(e, result){
            if(err) return cb(e, null);
            return cb(null, result);
        });
    });
}
/* USAGE */
try{
    myFunc(input, function(e, result){
        if(err) // handle operational error. 
        else{
            //continue what ever you need with result
        }
    })
}catch(e){
    //crash gracefully
}
```

However if we write this code in promise-based approach:

```
function myFunc (input){
    if(typeof input === 'undefined'){
        throw new Error('Invalid argument');
    }
    return asinc1(input)
    .then(asinc2);
}

/* USAGE */
myFunc(input)
.then(function(result){
    //continue what ever you need with result
}).catch(function(e){
    //handle both - programmatic and operational errors
})
```

there is no way to distinguish between error type thus I dont know what exactly to do if error happens.

Comment: It appears there was [an elaborate discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/promises/issues/10) on this very topic, if you haven't read it already. This issue may or may not be addressed in a later spec by extending the capability of `Promise()` or improving the standardization in the current spec for error-handling.

Comment: The problem with throwing (for programmatic errors) is that it doesn't work from asynchronous callbacks. The `try`/`catch` can only handle synchronous exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I have been doing some more research and found two possible solutions. However I dont feel 100% sure about them so would still love to hear other answers or someone to comment on my approach.

There are two options:

1. Mark the Error object as programmatic or operational at time of creation. Then you can bubble that object to upper lever and decide there what to do.
2. Implement two catching mechanisms in upper lever (caller)

To implement first one I have found two good ways. One is to create a [custom MyError object](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2828-creating-custom-error-objects-in-node-js-with-error-capturestacktrace.htm), second is simply adding additional flag:

```
if(programmatic error){
  let e = new Error('Message');
  e.isProgrammtic = true;
  throw e;
}
```

Now you can catch it and pass to global logger object where do a simple check if it is a programatic error and act accordingly.

Second option is possible using promise library like bluebird. They have [.error method](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error.html) that catches explicity operational errors. So in my example we could do something like this:

```
myFunc(input)
.then(function(result){
    //continue what ever you need with result
}).catch(function(e){
    //handle programatic errors. Crash gracefully and restart
}).error(function(e){
   // handle operational error. Dont crash
})
```

Comment: This is the solution. Notice that `error` is nothing but a helper method for using the first approach - it `catch`es all errors, checks whether they are operational to invoke the callback, and rethrows them otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

You can `return` `Promise.reject()` instead of `throw`ing `Error`

```js
function asinc1() {}

function asinc2() {}

function myFunc(input) {
  if (typeof input === "undefined") {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid argument'));
  }
  return asinc1(input)
    .then(asinc2);
}

/* USAGE */
myFunc(void 0)
  .then(function(result) {
    //continue what ever you need with result
  }).catch(function(e) {
    //handle both - programmatic and operational errors
    console.log(e)
  })
```

Comment: How does this distinguish between the type of error?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You compose the type of error that you are passing to `.reject()`. You can pass `new TypeError()` or other type of error

Comment: ...Then shouldn't you `return Promise.reject(new TypeError(...))`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You can do that if you want to. Or no error at all. The gist of the Answer, is gather Question correctly, is to use `Promise.reject()` to get to `.catch()`, where you can proceed with the `Promise` chain or not

Comment: Maybe I interpreted the question differently then, because based on what I thought he was asking, you haven't answered it. It seems to me like they're asking for a way to differentiate between different types of errors by catching them in different traps like in the first example, rather than attempting to merge the operational and programmatic error handling into one trap.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Then consider posting your Answer based on your interpretation of Question, for OP to have multiple potential solutions to select from?

Comment: I don't actually have an answer, I was just trying to clarify how you interpreted the question, because I seem to have initially misunderstood what issue you were addressing.

Comment: Patrick is correct, maybe I have not formulated question correctly. Problem is that there is only one place where both programmatic and operational errors are handled. In callback example I did know in which case to crash and restart but in promise based code I don't. However this answer raised another question from me - what is the difference between rejecting and throwing error? Is there a possibility to catch them separately?

Comment: @KārlisJanisels _"However this answer raised another question from me - what is the difference between rejecting and throwing error? Is there a possibility to catch them separately?"_ Yes, you can include `try..catch..finally` within function which returns a `Promise`. It really depends on how you decide to handle the specific cases.

Comment: Unless I miss my mark, this answer is just wrong. There's no difference in the promise chain between `throw`ing and `return`ing a rejected promise. You can't use that to differentiate between any type of error.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha If you review the code at `function myFunc (input){
    if(typeof input === 'undefined'){
        throw new Error('Invalid argument');
    }
    return asinc1(input)
    .then(asinc2);
}` OP `throw`s `Error`, though does not return a `Promise` object, resulting in the error not being caught at `.catch()` as no `Promise` is returned from `myFunc()`, which would have neither a `.then()` nor `.catch()` property associated with `myFunc()` call, negating the usage or purpose of `Promise` chain altogether

Comment: @MadaraUchiha  Yes, you missed that mark. https://jsfiddle.net/49aq3hkd/. Using `Promise.reject()` should resolve the issue with second example. `try..catch..finally` could be included within the body of the function; catch the thrown error, do other stuff, for example `return` `Promise.reject()` after handling the error.  A thrown error does not allow a `.catch()` chained to the function call to handle the error. Both `.then()` and `.catch()` cannot be chained to `undefined` `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha _"There's no difference in the promise chain between throwing and returning a rejected promise."_ There is a difference when `.then()` or `.catch()` is chained to a function call which `throw`s - `.then()` and `.catch()` are not reached. The appropriate course of action is for you to undo or "undownvote" your "downvote".

Comment: @guest271314 No, you're still wrong. Promise handlers are throw safe, meaning that you can `throw` inside of them and catch them in the next `.catch()` handler. `Promise.resolve(() => {throw new Error('hello');}).catch(err => console.log(err.message)); // logs 'hello'`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha That is not the code at Question. The code at Question does not return a `Promise`

Comment: That's fair, I did miss my mark. Please [edit] your answer a bit so that I may remove the downvote.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha What needs to be edited at Answer? The code at Question is clear, if the requirement is not as clear.

Comment: Downvotes are locked in after a while, unless the answer is edited. Unless you edit, I can't remove the downvote.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No worries. Your sharing the description of and exchange relevant to your reason for casting "downvote" and you actually re-examining your initial evaluation is equilibrium enough from perspective here.